# Multiple merges using base R

Tags: r, join, merge, data-manipulation

Using the "merge" function in (base) R, I have figured out how to do joins on a single column ...if that column has the same name in both tables: (in this example, I do a left join)

```
result = merge( x = table_a, y = table_b, by = "col_a", all.X = TRUE)
```

But is there a way to do this if the column names are not the same?

e.g.

```
result_1 = merge( x = table_a, y = table_b, by = "table_a$col_a = table_b$col_b", all.X = TRUE)
```

Could this also be done using multiple conditions?

```
result_2 = merge( x = table_a, y = table_b, by = c("table_a$col_a = table_b$col_b" & table_a$col_c = table_b$col_d" & table_a$col_e= table_b$col_f" ), all.X = TRUE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `merge`, we can have `by.x` and `by.y` as argument

```
merge( x = table_a, y = table_b, by.x = "col_a", by.y = "col_b", all.X = TRUE)
```

---

The syntax for a named `vector` in `by` (excluding the `"table_ar$"` would be a join syntax in `dplyr`